# Vector parallel to the line of intersection between two planes

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find a vector parallel to the line of intersection between two planes in $R^3$? I'm self-studying Introduction to linea algebra by Lang

Comment: Take the cross product of the planes normal vectors.

Comment: normal to normals.

Comment: The book expects it done without a cross product.